# How to extract the basis vectors from nullspace

Tags: maxima

Is there a way to extract the basis vectors from nullspace(A)?  For example, when I ran

`A : matrix([1,2,3,4], [2,2,4,4]);`
`nullspace(A);`

I got

`span(v1, v2)`

where v1 and v2 are the transpose of [0, -4, 0, 2] and [2,2,-2,0], respectively.

What I want to do is to use v1 & v2 to create another variable, e.g.

`B : matrix(v1, v2)`

Is there a way to do this, so that I don't need to read the screen and then manually enter v1 & v2 to create matrix B?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addcol` pastes together columns. Try this:

```
foo : nullspace (A);
B : apply (addcol, args (foo));
```

`args(foo)` returns the list of columns from the `span` expression (what you have labeled `v1` and `v2` above).